# exclude migrations files from flake8 and black in github actions

Tags: continuous-integration, github-actions, flake8, linter

I am looking for an approach to exclude django migration files from `black` and `flake8` in `github-actions`.

Here's what I've done so far:

- created a `.flake8` file with the following content in the root of project:

```
[flake8]
exclude = 
    */migrations/*
max-complexity = 10
max-line-length = 127
```

- a piece of my `github-actions.yml` content:

```
  linting:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: psf/black@stable
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: pip install flake8
      - name: Lint with flake8
        run: |
          # stop the build if there are Python syntax errors or undefined names
          flake8 . --count --select=E9,F63,F7,F82 --show-source --statistics
          # exit-zero treats all errors as warnings. The GitHub editor is 127 chars wide
          flake8 . --count --exit-zero --max-complexity=10 --max-line-length=127 --statistics
```

---

[UPDATE]:

Out:

```
6s
Run psf/black@stable
  with:
    options: --check --diff
    src: .
    jupyter: false
Run if [ "$RUNNER_OS" == "Windows" ]; then
  if [ "$RUNNER_OS" == "Windows" ]; then
    python $GITHUB_ACTION_PATH/action/main.py | tee -a $GITHUB_STEP_SUMMARY
  else
    python3 $GITHUB_ACTION_PATH/action/main.py | tee -a $GITHUB_STEP_SUMMARY
  fi
  shell: /usr/bin/bash --noprofile --norc -e -o pipefail {0}
  env:
    INPUT_OPTIONS: --check --diff
    INPUT_SRC: .
    INPUT_JUPYTER: false
    INPUT_BLACK_ARGS: 
    INPUT_VERSION: 
    pythonioencoding: utf-8
Installing black[colorama]==23.7.0...
--- /home/runner/work/bitpin-project/bitpin-project/bitpin/contents/migrations/0001_initial.py  2023-09-10 16:56:24.096492+00:00
+++ /home/runner/work/bitpin-project/bitpin-project/bitpin/contents/migrations/0001_initial.py  2023-09-10 16:56:29.804008+00:00
@@ -2,11 +2,10 @@
 
 from django.db import migrations, models
 
 
 class Migration(migrations.Migration):
-
     initial = True
 
     dependencies = []
 
     operations = [
would reformat /home/runner/work/bitpin-project/bitpin-project/bitpin/contents/migrations/0001_initial.py
--- /home/runner/work/bitpin-project/bitpin-project/bitpin/contents/migrations/0002_alter_content_text.py   2023-09-10 16:56:24.096492+00:00
+++ /home/runner/work/bitpin-project/bitpin-project/bitpin/contents/migrations/0002_alter_content_text.py   2023-09-10 16:56:29.804642+00:00
@@ -2,11 +2,10 @@
 
 from django.db import migrations, models
 
 
 class Migration(migrations.Migration):
-
     dependencies = [
         ("contents", "0001_initial"),
     ]
 
     operations = [
would reformat /home/runner/work/bitpin-project/bitpin-project/bitpin/contents/migrations/0002_alter_content_text.py
--- /home/runner/work/bitpin-project/bitpin-project/bitpin/star_ratings/migrations/0002_alter_rating_content.py 2023-09-10 16:56:24.096492+00:00
+++ /home/runner/work/bitpin-project/bitpin-project/bitpin/star_ratings/migrations/0002_alter_rating_content.py 2023-09-10 16:56:29.841362+00:00
@@ -3,11 +3,10 @@
 from django.db import migrations, models
 import django.db.models.deletion
 
 
 class Migration(migrations.Migration):
-
     dependencies = [
         ("contents", "0001_initial"),
         ("star_ratings", "0001_initial"),
     ]
 
would reformat /home/runner/work/bitpin-project/bitpin-project/bitpin/star_ratings/migrations/0002_alter_rating_content.py
--- /home/runner/work/bitpin-project/bitpin-project/bitpin/star_ratings/migrations/0003_alter_rating_content.py 2023-09-10 16:56:24.096492+00:00
+++ /home/runner/work/bitpin-project/bitpin-project/bitpin/star_ratings/migrations/0003_alter_rating_content.py 2023-09-10 16:56:29.855460+00:00
@@ -3,11 +3,10 @@
 from django.db import migrations, models
 import django.db.models.deletion
 
 
 class Migration(migrations.Migration):
-
     dependencies = [
         ("contents", "0001_initial"),
         ("star_ratings", "0002_alter_rating_content"),
     ]
 
would reformat /home/runner/work/bitpin-project/bitpin-project/bitpin/star_ratings/migrations/0003_alter_rating_content.py
--- /home/runner/work/bitpin-project/bitpin-project/bitpin/star_ratings/migrations/0001_initial.py  2023-09-10 16:56:24.096492+00:00
+++ /home/runner/work/bitpin-project/bitpin-project/bitpin/star_ratings/migrations/0001_initial.py  2023-09-10 16:56:29.868224+00:00
@@ -5,11 +5,10 @@
 from django.db import migrations, models
 import django.db.models.deletion
 
 
 class Migration(migrations.Migration):
-
     initial = True
 
     dependencies = [
         ("contents", "0001_initial"),
         migrations.swappable_dependency(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL),
would reformat /home/runner/work/bitpin-project/bitpin-project/bitpin/star_ratings/migrations/0001_initial.py
--- /home/runner/work/bitpin-project/bitpin-project/bitpin/star_ratings/migrations/0004_alter_userrating_score.py   2023-09-10 16:56:24.096492+00:00
+++ /home/runner/work/bitpin-project/bitpin-project/bitpin/star_ratings/migrations/0004_alter_userrating_score.py   2023-09-10 16:56:29.869773+00:00
@@ -3,11 +3,10 @@
 import django.core.validators
 from django.db import migrations, models
 
 
 class Migration(migrations.Migration):
-
     dependencies = [
         ("star_ratings", "0003_alter_rating_content"),
     ]
 
     operations = [
would reformat /home/runner/work/bitpin-project/bitpin-project/bitpin/star_ratings/migrations/0004_alter_userrating_score.py
--- /home/runner/work/bitpin-project/bitpin-project/bitpin/star_ratings/migrations/0005_alter_rating_content.py 2023-09-10 16:56:24.096492+00:00
+++ /home/runner/work/bitpin-project/bitpin-project/bitpin/star_ratings/migrations/0005_alter_rating_content.py 2023-09-10 16:56:29.880033+00:00
@@ -4,11 +4,10 @@
 import django.db.models.deletion
 import django.utils.timezone
 
 
 class Migration(migrations.Migration):
-
     dependencies = [
         ("contents", "0002_alter_content_text"),
         ("star_ratings", "0004_alter_userrating_score"),
     ]
 
would reformat /home/runner/work/bitpin-project/bitpin-project/bitpin/star_ratings/migrations/0005_alter_rating_content.py
--- /home/runner/work/bitpin-project/bitpin-project/bitpin/users/migrations/0001_initial.py 2023-09-10 16:56:24.096492+00:00
+++ /home/runner/work/bitpin-project/bitpin-project/bitpin/users/migrations/0001_initial.py 2023-09-10 16:56:29.973121+00:00
@@ -5,11 +5,10 @@
 from django.db import migrations, models
 import django.utils.timezone
 
 
 class Migration(migrations.Migration):
-
     initial = True
 
     dependencies = [
         ("auth", "0012_alter_user_first_name_max_length"),
     ]
would reformat /home/runner/work/bitpin-project/bitpin-project/bitpin/users/migrations/0001_initial.py

Oh no!   
8 files would be reformatted, 35 files would be left unchanged.

Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

Comment: this seems to work for me?  what sort of problems are you seeing?

Comment: @anthonysottile actually doesn't work. might it be related to the path of mentioned files?

Comment: "doesn't work" is not a helpful report.  you should say what you're seeing and not assume that we know and can see your screen.  if you would have shown some output or said "it changed files" it would have been immediately obvious you weren't talking about flake8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I overcame the problem. Actually, the issue was not related to the `flake8` it was related to the `black` linter by the following line:

`- uses: psf/black@stable`

So to tackle this issue (excluding migration files) I created a `pyproject.toml` in the project root with the following content:

```
[tool.black]
exclude = '''
(
  /(
      \.git
    | \.hg
    | \.mypy_cache
    | \.tox
    | \.venv
    | _build
    | buck-out
    | build
    | dist
  )/
| migrations
)
'''
```